# How to align cell entries in multirow environment of table?

Tags: tables, multirow

I am trying to write a table in multirow environment. However, my entries are not aligned properly. Code is pasted below. Screenshot of output is attached. Can somebody help me to solve the problem?Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[sigconf, authordraft]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs} % For formal tables
\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
 \caption{Quality Metrics which require reference image}
  \label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular}{cccccccccl}

    Sl.No.&Metric&Band&DWT -rule 1&DWT -rule 2&DWT -rule 3&DWT-rule 4&PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi  \\  \hline
%    \midrule
   \multirow{4}{*}{1}  &\multirow{4}{*}{Rel Bias}     & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   \multirow{4}{*}{2} &\multirow{4}{*}{ Rel VAR}      & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
    \multirow{4}{*}{3} &\multirow{4}{*}{ Rel SDD}     & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi\\
                                    & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
                                & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\

%    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of table generated]

Answer (score 5):

The second row was missing (two `&` were needed), therefore the contents were incorrectly aligned.

I have added the `*`in the second argument of the `\multirow` command and corrected the ending of a table row (`\\`).

The resulting **MWE** (note that it is minimal, I have reduced it):

```
\documentclass[sigconf, authordraft]{acmart}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Quality Metrics which require reference image}
\label{tab:table1}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccl}
Sl.No. & Metric & Band & DWT -rule 1 & DWT -rule 2 & DWT -rule 3 & DWT-rule 4 & PCA & GIHS & GIHS-Choi  \\
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{1} & \multirow{4}{*}{Rel Bias} & Green & DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2 & DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4 & PCA & GIHS & GIHS-Choi \\
 & & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
 & & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
 & & Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This results in:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

In addition to inserting missing `&` symbols in data rows 2-4, 6-8, and 10-12, you may want to rethink the layout of the table. E.g., instead of using `\multirow` to treat the contents of the first two columns in a special way, simply get rid of the `\multirow` wrappers and add a bit of vertical whitespace after rows 4 and 8 (via `\addlinespace` instructions). In addition, in view of the fact that the table takes up almost the full width of the text block, why not "make if official" and employ a `tabular*` environment that does take up the full available space?

[image]

```
\documentclass[sigconf, authordraft]{acmart}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\caption{Quality Metrics which require reference image}
\label{tab:table1}
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{10}{l} }
%   \toprule
    Sl.No. & Metric & Band & DWT-rule 1 & DWT-rule 2 &
    DWT-rule 3 & DWT-rule 4 & PCA & GIHS & GIHS-Choi \\
  \midrule
   1 & Rel Bias   
   &  Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   \addlinespace
   2 & Rel VAR 
   &  Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   \addlinespace
   3 & Rel SDD
   &  Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi\\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
   && Green& DWT-rule1 & DWT-rule2& DWT-rule3 & DWT-rule4& PCA&GIHS&GIHS-Choi \\
%  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```